# Error inheriting a module in a mavenized GWT project

Tags: java, maven, gwt, smartgwt

After adding this dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.eaio.uuid</groupId>
   <artifactId>uuid</artifactId>
   <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I get an error by jetty on the module load event:

> no source code available for com.eaio.uuid; did you forget to inherit the module? unable to find com.client.myproject..`

What am I missing?

Comment: inherit the module in your *.gwt.xml

Comment: can you suggest me the module name. I am inheriting the module name it also shows error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any of the classes in that artifact in your GWT compiled code, then the source code needs to be available, either packaged in the jar or as a source jar (remember that's another dependency).

You'll have to look for a .gwt.xml file in the jar, as this will be the name you need to inherit in your own GWT descriptor, eg. if the file is called `com/eaio/UUID.gwt.xml` you should

```
...
<inherits name="com.eaio.UUID" />
...
```

If one isn't available, just create your own with a simple `<source path="..." />` and stick in the right package in your own project (still provided the source *is* actually available!)

Cheers,

Comment: on launching myproject it shows error: An internal error occurred during: "Launching myproject (1)".
Invalid thread access

Comment: That has nothing to do with the GWT compile issue you asked about. Start a new question and fill in the details (GWT version, OS, sample code to reproduce, full stack trace etc.)

Comment: Unable to find 'UUID.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
can u tell me how can i solve this @anders R. Bystrup

Comment: Read my answer again. Are you sure you actually have the UUID source code in the jar-file?